# what is intent code in android?

Tags: android, android-intent

i don't know what is problem???
this code don't work and don't go to second activity and i don't get error i use blue stack emulator and it crashed when in use intent button

```
  Button button 1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
    button1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Intent i = new Intent(Activity_main.this, Activity_two.class);
            startActivity(i);

        }
    });
```

Comment: thank you the problem was in manifest

Comment: A very common mistake. I turned my comment into an answer, so that you can accept it - and remove the post from the Unanswered Question Queue.

Answer (score 0):

Declare `Activity_two` in your **Manifest**.

Something like:

```
<activity name="Activity_two" />
```

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: @ManishDubey This actually **IS** the answer. Please take your time and read the OP's comment: `thank you the problem was in manifest`